# wdio scrollIntoView() returns some errors :(

Tags: wdio

I'm trying to scroll UI page down to the given element.

```
const elem = await $('#trades-show');
await elem.scrollIntoView();
```

but in return I'm getting:

```
TypeError: browser.getElementRect is not a function
at runMicrotasks(<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Can someone please help with this?